# Unit of Work Not Saving On POST Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am following the Repository pattern and implementing UnitOfWork.

**Here is the issue:**

Within the `EmployeeController`, there is a post call titled `AddEmployee()`. This action method gets the appropriate data and the result comes back successful, but **the data is not getting saved to the database**. The action method is also calling the `SaveEmployee()` method, which should in theory save the data.

> **Git Repo:** https://bitbucket.org/ChaseHardin/myapp
>
> **Question:** Why isn't the UnitOfWork saving the database changes?

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage AddEmployee([FromBody]Employee employee)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         _employeeService.AddEmployee(employee);
         _employeeService.SaveEmployee();

         return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }

         return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
}
```

**Service:**

```
  public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
    {
        private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public EmployeeService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        }

        public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
        {
            return _employeeRepository.GetById(id);
        }

        public void SaveEmployee()
        {
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

        public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            _employeeRepository.Add(employee);
        }
    }

    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        Employee GetEmployee(int id);
        void SaveEmployee();
        void AddEmployee(Employee employee);
    }
```

**UnitOfWork**

```
 public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
 {
     private readonly IDbFactory dbFactory;
     private MyAppEntities dbContext;

     public UnitOfWork(IDbFactory dbFactory)
     {
         this.dbFactory = dbFactory;
     }

     public MyAppEntities DbContext
     {
         get { return dbContext ?? (dbContext = dbFactory.Init()); }
     }

     public void Commit()
     {
         DbContext.Commit();
     }
 }

 public interface IUnitOfWork
 {
     void Commit();
 }
```

**MyAppEntities:**

```
  public class MyAppEntities : DbContext
  {
      public MyAppEntities() : base("MyAppEntities") { }

      public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

      public virtual void Commit()
      {
          SaveChanges();
      }
  }
```

**EmployeeRepository**

```
 public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
    {
        private readonly IEmployeeRepository _employeeRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

        public EmployeeService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _employeeRepository = employeeRepository;
        }

        public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
        {
            return _employeeRepository.GetById(id);
        }

        public void SaveEmployee()
        {
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

        public void AddEmployee(Employee employee)
        {
            _employeeRepository.Add(employee);
        }
    }

    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        Employee GetEmployee(int id);
        void SaveEmployee();
        void AddEmployee(Employee employee);
    }
```

**Base Repo**

```
 public abstract class BaseRepository <T> where T : class
    {
        private MyAppEntities _dataContext;
        private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbSet;
        protected IDbFactory DbFactory { get; private set; }
        protected MyAppEntities DbContext
        {
            get { return _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = DbFactory.Init()); }
        }

        protected BaseRepository(IDbFactory dbFactory)
        {
            DbFactory = dbFactory;
            _dbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
        }

        #region Implementation
        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Update(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Attach(entity);
            _dataContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> objects = _dbSet.Where<T>(where).AsEnumerable();
            foreach (T obj in objects)
                _dbSet.Remove(obj);
        }

        public virtual T GetById(int id)
        {
            return _dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
        {
            return _dbSet.ToList();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return _dbSet.Where(where).ToList();
        }

        public T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return _dbSet.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<T>();
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        void Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
        T GetById(int id);
        T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where);
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged and stepped through an end to end process of adding and saving data.

Comment: Yes sir... It returns an "OK" response and doesn't throw any errors, which makes isolating harder.

Comment: Just for debugging, in your `MyAppEntities` class put `int count = SaveChanges();` int your `Commit()` method and put a break point there. then try to save a record. check if you get back a number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is your IOC scope. In `App_Start` you are binding your objects with the default [Transient Scope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes). This is causing multiple contexts to be created, and you are adding the employee in one context and calling `SaveChanges()` on another.

Update your Ninject bindings to use `InSingletonScope()` or `InRequestScope()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response... If you look at the `MyAppEntities`, you'll see that the `Commit()` is actually calling `SaveChanges()`... Shouldn't that handle the issue?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it... Just a moment. Here's my repo: https://bitbucket.org/ChaseHardin/myapp

Comment: Okay, so should it look something like `kernel.Bind<Employee>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();`

Comment: No you should update the DbFactory binding: `kernel.Bind<IDbFactory>().To<DbFactory>().InSingletonScope();`

Answer (score 1):

As @TimS mentioned it is totally about how you register your services at application start. I had same problem with similar pattern while I was using [autofac](https://autofac.org/) instead of Ninject.

With autofac if you don't choose lifetime scope it is *[Instance Per Dependency](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#id1)* scope as default. By this scope for each request an instance of registered object returns; this cause multiple context at same scope and when you commit your changes by unitofwork instance it just commit wrong instance of Context. To avoiding this you have to use single instance scope or better for this case *[Instance Per Lifetime Scope](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#id3)*

> This scope applies to nested lifetimes. A component with per-lifetime
>   scope will have at most a single instance per nested lifetime scope.
>
> This is useful for objects specific to a single unit of work that may
>   need to nest additional logical units of work. Each nested lifetime
>   scope will get a new instance of the registered dependency.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<DbFactory>().As<IDbFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```